# Is lexical closure an attribute of the execution context of a function?

Tags: javascript, closures

I understand that when I define a function in some lexical environment, it decides the lexical closure the function has access to and also the variables from outer scopes and in the prototype chain.

My question is what happens when we change the execution context of a function explicitly using `bind` or `call` or `apply`. How does this affect the variables that ought to have been available in the function due to lexical closure and also variables that were supposed to be found in the prototype chain.

My instinct says the previous closure is replaced and a new prototype chain should be available and variable might or might not be found in the new prototype chain based on scenario, but then it begs the question if I am creating a new execution context, thereby there is a new lexical closure then can I somehow insert some other variables into this newly created lexical closure?

Also is there a way to change the `this` of a function before it is called but preserve its previous lexical closure?

Comment: `bind`, `call` and `apply` only change the `this` value of a function's context. They don't change the closure env. So any "parent" env. variables are still available, even when using the mentioned methods.

Comment: @SebastienDaniel Please add it as an answer, I realize the my mistake now

Comment: the answer has been posted, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bind`, `call` and `apply` only change the `this` value of a function (*i.e. its context*), not its scope (*i.e. environment*).

So any *parent* env. variables are still available, even when using the mentioned methods. Only `this` will be changed.